# how to insert rows via loop in MySQL shell (no PHP)

Tags: mysql

I would like to execute a loop in phpmyadmin which inserts rows in a table. So far I have:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_my_rows()

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_my_rows()
BEGIN
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 376;

WHILE i<405 DO
        INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships(object_id,term_taxonomy_id,term_order) VALUES (i,16,0);
        SET i=i+1;
END WHILE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL insert_my_rows()
```

With this, I get an error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_my_rows()

CREATE PROCEDURE ins' at line 1
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from around the column name

Comment: i still get #1305 - PROCEDURE sunny.insert_my_rows does not exist

Comment: Can you please show your procedure?

Comment: @Mike post updated with current procedure

Comment: the clue is in the first line

Comment: @bsapaka I knew the error is not with the code you posted earlier and that is why I asked you for the entire code. Kums posted the correct answer below Change `DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_my_rows();` to 
`DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_my_rows;`

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for the `DROP PROCEDURE` statement is incorrect!

Change

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_my_rows()
```

to

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_my_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to end the statement with the proper delimiter. Change `END` to `END$$`.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the delimiter only while you make blocks of statements, so during the procedure definition. The `DROP PROCEDURE` and `CALL` statements needs delimiters too.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_my_rows;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_my_rows()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 376;

    WHILE i<405 DO
        INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships(object_id,term_taxonomy_id,term_order) VALUES (i,16,0);
        SET i=i+1;
    END WHILE;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL insert_my_rows();

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_my_rows;
```